# Datetime usage with in <> operators

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a datetime definition that I do not know how to use of. What exactly is the expression between the <> signs? it returns Boolean but how?

```
bool x= DateTime.Now.AddDays(20) <DateTime.Now && DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)> DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: These are `less than` and `greater than`, respectively,

Comment: Those are operators in C#, not a *tag*.

Comment: `bool x= (DateTime.Now.AddDays(20) < DateTime.Now) && (DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) > DateTime.Now);`

Comment: Note that `&&` is a boolean and.

Comment: extract some variables and it gets more clear: `DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20), d2 = DateTime.Now, d3 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10); bool x = d1 < d2 && d3 > d2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format it differently and it will be easy to see that it's two less than/greater than signs:

```
bool x = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20) < DateTime.Now 
      && DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) > DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Sorry. My fault. I thought there was a use between in <>. What a shame :)

Comment: @Halim `<TYPE>` is used with generics, for example `List<string>`, but the bit in the middle has to be a type.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool x = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20) < DateTime.Now //(1)
      && DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) > DateTime.Now; //(2)
```

To English:

(1): Is (Today + 20 days) smaller than Today?
// We have `False`

(2): Is (Today + 10 days) greater than Today?
// We have `True`

And Finally `(1) && (2)` will return your result `x`

// We have `x = True && False = False`

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly is the expression between the <> signs? it returns Boolean but how?

As already mentioned in the code that you posted `<` and `>` and `&&` are [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) and not tags

the first `<` is a ["less than" relational operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/less-than-operator)

the last `>` is a ["greater than" relational operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/greater-than-operator)

These operators compare the operands at each side of the operator and return `true` or `false`.

the middle operator `&&` is called [The conditional-AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) and it

> performs a logical-AND of its bool operands

This is why the whole statement returns `bool`